# Telegram.Bot SendLocationAsync returns "Input string was not in a correct format" only when running as a Service

Tags: telegram, topshelf

I am running a C# .Net Core console App as a Service (using Topshelf) and all is fine except Telegram.Bot SendLocationAsync that returns an error: "Input string was not in a correct format"

In Debug Mode it works fine as well as a Release Console App. Other Telegram messages work 100%.
It is definitely only when I run the App as a Service.

Any ideas would be welcome?

Some sample code used:

```
        string locString = "-25.2567752,28.7920051";
        try
        {
            string[] cam_loc = locString.Split(",");
            double Lat = Convert.ToDouble(cam_loc[0]);
            double Long = Convert.ToDouble(cam_loc[1]);
            var Result1 = await Bot.SendLocationAsync(chatId: -625759052, latitude: (float)Lat, longitude: (float)Long);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Error Location Send: " + ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem found was the culture info that did not parse correctly

the following fixed the problem:

double.TryParse(cam_loc[0], NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out 
    Lat_)

```
if (double.TryParse(cam_loc[0], NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out 
    Lat_) && double.TryParse(cam_loc[1], NumberStyles.Number, 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out Long_))
{
    Log.Debug("Lat/Long values: " + Lat_.ToString() + " / " + Long_.ToString());
    try
    {
        var Result1 = await Bot.SendLocationAsync(chatId: vp.cliGroup, latitude: 
    (float)Lat_, longitude: (float)Long_);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error("Error Location Send: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
else
    Log.Debug("Lat/Long (err) values: " + Lat_.ToString() + " / " + Long_.ToString());
```